# SpresenseSDKコマンドシェルのイニシャル時exportが機能しない

Tags: spresense

SpresenseSDKのコマンドシェルのイニシャル時に、以下のようにexportで変数定義しましたが、値が空白になってしまいます。
・旧SDKバージョン（v2.2.0）では、うまく機能しておりました。
・新SDKバージョン（v2.4.0）では、うまくいきません。変数の値が空白になってしまいます。
例えばコマンドの使い方が変わったとか、Config設定で足りないものとかありますでしょうか？

- SDKコンフィグ設定

```
・CONFIG_NSH_VARS＝Y
・NSH_DISABLE_ENV＝N
```

- イニシャル時(init.rc等)

```
sh /mnt/sd0/export.txt
sh /mnt/sd0/sample1
```

- export.txt内

```
export DEF_SAMPLE1 0
export DEF_SAMPLE2 "/mnt/sd0/"
```

- sample1内

```
sh /mnt/sd0/sample2 &
```

- sample2内

```
echo $DEF_SAMPLE1      ← 新SDKではNG。空白データ。旧SDKではOK
echo ${DEF_SAMPLE2}   ← 新SDKではNG。空白データ。旧SDKではOK
```

Answer (score 1):

NuttX Environment Variables によると、環境変数はタスクグループごとに管理されているようです。
https://nuttx.apache.org/docs/latest/reference/user/09_env_vars.html

- task: タスク作成時、環境変数が子タスクに複製されるがそれぞれ独立したものになる
- thread: スレッド間で環境変数は共有される

`sh` でプロセスを作成してそこで `export` してもそのプロセスが終了すると同時に環境変数は消えます。旧SDKバージョンで動いていた理由は不明ですが、新SDKバージョンの動作が本来の仕様通りの振る舞いのようです（ドキュメントとコードを読む限り）。

`sh` の代りに `source` を使えば、この質問のケースは意図通りに動作するのではないかと思います。

- イニシャル時(init.rc等)

```
source /mnt/sd0/export.txt
sh /mnt/sd0/sample1
```